# nonsingularity of a diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix which is sort of diagonally dominant but not quite.

Each row is a probability vector (nonngative and sums up to one).

I have for any $i$ and $j\neq i$:

- $a_{ii} > a_{ij}$
- $a_{ii} > a_{ji}$

I wonder whether it must be nonsingular.

Comment: Have you tried computing an enclosure of its eigenvalues? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem

Comment: @cvanaret According to the question, the row vectors are probability vectors, and so its Gershgorin circles each contain $0$. Traditional diagonal dominance purposely excludes $0$ from each Gershgorin circle, which implies invertability, but that's not what's happening here.

Answer (score 1):

When $A$ is $n\times n$ for some $n\ge4$, the answer is negative. Here is a counterexample for the case $n=4$:
$$
A=A_4:=\frac{1}{8}\pmatrix{
3&1&2&2\\
1&3&2&2\\
2&2&3&1\\
2&2&1&3}.
$$
This doubly stochastic matrix is singular because the sum of its first two columns is equal to the sum of the other two.

When $n>4$, consider
$$
A=(1-t)\pmatrix{A_4\\ &I_{n-4}}+\frac{t}{n}E
$$
where $E$ is the matrix of ones and $t>0$ is sufficiently small. The matrix $A$ is doubly stochastic because it is a convex combination of two doubly stochastic matrices $A_4\oplus I_{n-4}$ and $\frac1nE$. It is singular because the sum of its first two columns is equal to the sum of the third and the fourth ones. It is easy to check that $a_{ii}>\max(a_{ij},a_{ji})$ for every $i\ne j$.